# Best way to send html email in C# without disrupting the TCP connection

Tags: c#, tcp

I'm working on an app that connects to a server using TCP connection. The server is a C# console app running on a VPS and there are thousands of clients (Android Apps) that are gonna connect to this server and every single one of this clients will send dozens of packets per second to server and server responds to each packet. So this is a part of the code on server:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Threading;

namespace Server
{
    class Program
    {

        private static Thread thread;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ConsoleThread));
            thread.Start();
            // Initialize TCP and start listening for packages from clients
        }

        private static void ConsoleThread()
        {
            while (true)
            {

            }
        }

        public static void SendTestMail()
        {
            // What is the best way to do this
            SendMail("target@example.com", "Whatever", "<p>This is a test message.</p>");
        }

        public static void SendMail(string to, string subject, string html)
        {
            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
            MailMessage mail = null;
            try
            {
                mail = new MailMessage("xxxx@gmail.com", to, subject, html);
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                smtpClient.Port = 587;
                smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
                smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
                smtpClient.Send(mail);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (mail != null)
                {
                    mail.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Sometimes server should send a mail to a client. I was wondering if there is a possibility that sending a mail could disrupt or delay server from responding to clients? If yes then what is your suggestion on how to call SendMail method? This is what I could think of:

```
public static void SendTestMail()
{
    Thread mailThread = new Thread(() => SendMail("target@example.com", "Whatever", "<p>This is a test message.</p>"));
    mailThread.Start();
}
```

Also I would like to know your thoughts on the whole thing. Is using TCP between a virtual private server and a lot of clients is a good idea (only integer and string variables will be transferred between them)? For example a VPS with the following specifications can support how many clients?
CPU: 4vCores
RAM: 4GB
Hard: 50GB NVMe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SmtpClient supports [SendAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient.sendasync?view=netframework-4.5) so sending the email won't block your thread.
For the general question - Can you measure the resources usage of your app with a single connection? e.g. if you run it on your development environment and connect with a client then how much CPU and RAM is being used?